# Itext 7 license

Tags: java, android, itext, itext7

I can't seem to figure how to load the license file for itext 7. I got the trial license but I don't know where to put it, classpath? where is classpath? and when I put it anywhere how can I get its path in order to put it in the

```
LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(new File("path/to/itextkey.json"));
```

I keep getting the error

```
License file can not be null.
```

whenever I try putting it somewhere and adding the path but I am certain I am doing it wrong, can someone explain to me how?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you add the license key file to your project.
For me, I used AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory for the location of my file.
Finally, in Solution Explorer, I highlighted the license key file and in the properties window, I set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always" to make it available during runtime.

Answer (score -1):

In order to load iText 7 trial JSON license file, you need to have iText 7.2.4 and licensing base 4.0.4 jar file into your workspace. Once these dependencies are pulled through maven into your local workspace then you can invoke below line of code to load trial license. Please refer step by step installation guideline on how to pull dependencies here at https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/installation-guidelines/installing-the-itext-license-key-and-license-key-library-for-java-and-net

LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(new File("path/to/itextkey.json"));

Comment: I have both of them in my android studio IDE, my question clearly was where exactly am I supposed to put the JSON file? and how exactly do I get the path? 
An example would do it for me.

Comment: Did you check the API documentation of loadLicenseFile method? It accepts File well as InputStream as an argument. So, it really doesn't matter, and you can keep JSON file wherever you want and pass that file system path or Inputstream as an argument to load your JSON fie using loadLicenseFile method.

Comment: can you give an example please? 
Like code?

Comment: LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(new File("src/main/resources/load/license.json"));
LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(new File("C:\\load\\license.json"));